# Bootstrap 4 button inside card component that has click event

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

I have the following html code to generate a basic card using bootstrap 4. 
I want to change the style of the card when the card is clicked. However, if the button is clicked, I dont want the style to change.
At the moment, when I click test1 button, I will also activate the function onCardClick(). 
Is there a way to do this such that when I click on the test button1 only Test1() executes

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card" (click)="onCardClick()">
        <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title d-inline">Some Title</h4>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onTest1()">test1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onTest2()">test2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You're using Angular? If so post that code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this to stop the event from bubbling up the dom:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card"
           (click)="onCardClick()">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title d-inline">Some Title</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"
                  (click)="onTest1($event)">test1
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary"
                  (click)="onTest2($event)">test2
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your component:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
})

export class Test
{
    onTest1(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //or event.preventDefault()
        //stuff to run
    }

    onTest2(event)
    {
        event.stopPropagation();
        //stuff to run
    }

}
```